# Excel, Search in a column not for first match but for a match in second column and return colum 3

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, excel-2013

I need an excel formula that searchs in column 1 for a value, not the first value but the value that also matches a value in the same raw in column 2, then return the column 3.

for example:[screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kDam.png)

I need to get the value 100. It will be duplicated values in column 1 and in column 2, but always only 1 match. I need to get that result. and it needs to be in a formula. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`=INDEX(E:E,MATCH("BL1"&"|"&"001",C:C&"|"&D:D,0))`
This may require to be entered as `ctrl+shift+enter` in excel versions prior to Office365